# Maximum Concurrent Bluetooth LE Devices on iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am looking for definitive values for the maximum number of concurrent BLE devices you can connect to on both iOS and Android. I have done my own research and testing and it is not consistent. The Bluetooth LE spec does not limit the number of simultaneous connections, but the platforms have added caps due to memory constraints.

On Android 7 I was able to connect to 22 BLE peripherals simultaneously. One Android 9, I was only able to connect to 12 BLE peripherals at a time. And on Android 10 I have at times been able to connect to 12 BLE peripherals simultaneously and the same setup could connect to 14 BLE peripherals simultaneously at other times. All of this testing was on Samsung Galaxy Tab 10 hardware.

iOS is a similar story. I have been able to connect to 8 BLE peripherals simultaneously on iOS 9, 12 BLE peripherals simultaneously on iOS 10, 11, and 12, and 15 BLE peripherals simultaneously on iOS 13. I have not tested iOS 14, yet. This testing was done on iPad Mini 2s, iPad Mini 5s, and iPhone 7+s with the same results on all hardware. Others on this site claim to have seen as many as 20 concurrent devices on iPhone 6S with iOS 10 - I cannot confirm that.

I have seen lots of similar numbers from others' testing and some have even referenced documentation from Android and Apple calling these values out. I have not been able to find anything in the documentation from the last few releases of Android or iOS that call out these maximum values.

Could anyone help point me out to the true, documented values? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The sad truth is that there are no documented values anywhere to be found, for most devices. The manufacturers don't state the Bluetooth limitations anywhere. When the product goes through Bluetooth certification and declaration, it however needs to specify every single supported Bluetooth feature supported, but not how many connections it can handle.

The BLE spec does not state any limitation, so it's up to the Bluetooth implementation to decide.

First, the Bluetooth chip (controller) usually has its own restriction. The HCI does not expose any functionality to query the maximum number of connections, so the host stack does not know what the controller's limitations are. First when the maximum is reached and the host tries to connect another device, the controller will return an HCI error code of maximum connections reached.

All Bluetooh chips have unique limitations. They usually range from somewhere between 3 to 20, as you have noticed. This limitation is more important than the specific OS and version the device runs.

Now if we look at the Android Bluetooth host stack, it has a hardcoded limit of 7 connections the last time I checked the source code. So in Pixel and Nexus phones, which run the "vanilla" Android, the limit will be 7, even though the Bluetooth chip can itself handle more (I've recompiled AOSP with an increased limit and verified this on Nexus 6P). I've seen that other manufacturers, such as Samsung, increase this limit to match what the Bluetooth chip actually supports.

Anyway, looking at specific OS versions will not give any useful information; you must test each device individually.