# Bluetooth LE Low Energy BLE – Multiple simultaneous connections (more than 7)

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I am looking for ANY way to connect more than 7 (at least 13) Bluetooth LE devices to an Android device. As I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360109/maximum-concurrent-bluetooth-le-devices-on-ios-and-android), this depends first on the hardware, but then also on a limitation in the Android operating system. However, there are devices that can connect to more than 7 devices, because the hardware supports more devices and the manufacturer has adapted Android accordingly.

I tried it with a Galaxy S9, with a Pixel 6 Pro, with a Raspberry, with a Rock 4 SE and with a Xiaomi MI TV stick.

Can anyone tell me how to get an Android device or sbc that works?

Comment: How did you try to connect multiple BLE devices and how many did you get to connect?

Comment: I tried to connect with an Android App made with App Inventor directly (no pairing). Ich can connect to 7 devices. When I try to connect to an 8th, I get a connection timeout error.

Comment: Consider adding all relevant tags that specifes the platform, programming language etc.

Comment: App Inventor 2, Bluetooth LE Extension
I think the problem does not affect the programming but the hardware and the operating system --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64360109/maximum-concurrent-bluetooth-le-devices-on-ios-and-android

Comment: So you are asking us for specific devices that allow more than 7 simultaneous connections?

Comment: Yes, that's right.